# karma $q not resolve when wrapping a third-party promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am wrapping a native js promise with $q. in the test the native promise is resolved but the $q is not.
I am using karma jasmine

```
it('promise', () => {
    let $q, $rootScope;
    inject((_$q_ :  any, _$rootScope_ : any, ) => {
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    });

    const deferred = $q.defer();

    const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve('Stuff worked!');
    });

    promise.then(function (x) {
        console.log('inside then', x); // THIS IS RESOLVING
        deferred.resolve(x);
    }).catch(function (x) {
        deferred.reject(x);
    });


    deferred.promise.then((x) => {
        console.log(x); // THIS IS NEVER RESOLVED
    }, (y) => {
        console.log(y);
    });

    $rootScope.$apply();
    $rootScope.$digest();

});
```

I have even tried to wrap it in $timeout...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no error. just not resolving

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. use done function

```
 fit('promise', (done) => {
    let $q, $rootScope;
    inject((_$q_: any, _$rootScope_: any) => {
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    });

    const deferred = $q.defer();

    const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve('Stuff worked!');
    });

    deferred.promise.then((x) => {
        done(); // THIS WILL CAUSE KARMA T WAIT AND RESOLV THE PROMISE 
        //expect.......
    }, (y) => {
        console.log(y);
    });

    promise.then(function (x) {
        console.log('inside then', x);
        deferred.resolve(x);
        $rootScope.$apply(); //MUST ADD APPLY HERE TOO
    }).catch(function (x) {
        deferred.reject(x);
    });


    $rootScope.$apply();
    $rootScope.$digest();

});
```